# Do you use Tab Stacking of Opera or Tab Panarama of Firefox

Tags: firefox, tabs, opera

Recently I installed Firefox 13 Beta(http://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/all-beta.html). It has the new feature, new tab page like Google Chrome. It's that I want and I wait for. It shows the pages that I visited recently.

When lauching Firefox 4, I surprised at Tab Panorama. I used to be excited with it. But now, I don't use it. Opera Tab Stacking is also very interesting feature. But I don't use it now either.

I wonder usage of them. Do they have unique value that other features can't provide?

Answer (score 2):

I don't use Opera, but Tab Panorama in Firefox is mostly meant for organizing tabs into groups. User can have different groups of tabs for work, learning, fun... this way tab bar isn't filled with dozens of tabs that are not essential for the current task.

Sometimes you don't want to close all the tabs and would just like to save them for a little while. So tab groups can also be used as temporary "bookmarks folders".

Another good thing is that Firefox only preloads tabs in currently selected group on start, so the start-up times are better as well. However, Firefox 13 has "tabs on demand", so this may not be so relevant anymore.

Basically there is no need for it if you don't have dozens of opened tabs. It's just another way for people to organize their tabs.

Answer (score 1):

Tab stacking in Opera is useful for me when I use my netbook and I have a couple dozen tabs open. Otherwise, the small screen makes my tabs tiny.